# POST Empty Error

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Its  my password change page.

I'm trying to newpass,oldpass,newpasstwo get and change. But.. all posts giving null. Sorry for bad english, why i cant get this posts?

```
    <form action="index.php?bolum=panel&secenek=sifredegistir" autocomplete="off" method="post">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Eski Şifreniz</td><td>:</td><td><input type="password" name="oldpass" id="oldpass"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yeni Şifreniz</td><td>:</td><td><input type="password" name="newpass" id="newpass"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yeni Şifreniz <i>(tekrar)</i></td><td>:</td><td><input type="password" id="newpasstwo" name="newpasstwo"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td><input class="px150" type="submit" value="Şifremi Değiştir"></td>
    </table>
  </form>

  </div></div></div>

<?php

}
elseif ($_GET['secenek'] == "sifredegistir") 
{
    $accname = strip_tags($_SESSION['muyuser']);
    $oldpass = $_POST['oldpass'];
    $newpass = $_POST['newpass'];
    $newpasstwo = $_POST['newpasstwo'];
    $sifre = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$accname' AND user_password='$oldpass'"); 
    $sifredogrula = mysql_num_rows($sifre);
    if(empty($oldpass) || empty($newpasstwo) || empty($newpass))
    {
      echo '<div align="center"><b>Lütfen tüm alanları doldurun!</b></div>';
    }
    elseif ($sifredogrula < 1) {
      echo $accname;
      echo $oldpass;
      echo newpass;
      echo newpasstwo;
      echo '<div align="center"><b>Bilgileriniz yanlış, lütfen dikkatli doldurun.</b></div>';
    }
```

Comment: can you see the values using `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: Note that your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. At a minimum, you must call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on each of the `$_POST` values passed into your query. This is not optional.  Consider switching to an API supporting prepared statements, like MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: check where the control goes in if statements...

Comment: please explain.. are you posting to this same page or `index.php` you are mentioning as target is different

Comment: More info code needed, the error doesn't appear to be with what you supplied

Answer (score 0):

session_start();

somewhere before your $_POST['oldpass']; line.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting your username alone in SELECT * from users is sufficient.

Change `echo newpass;` to `echo $newpass;`

Change `echo newpasstwo;` to `echo $newpasstwo;`

To change password you need to add

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_password='$newpasstwo;'
WHERE username='$accname'");
```

Comment: In addition: And what if query fails? `mysql_query()` returns a value btw on success/failure respectively. This should be: `if ( mysql_query(...) != FALSE ){ .... }`

Comment: That is if the username is retrieved wrongly or if the source is incorrect